# Is force applied if there is no one to oppose it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics

If I move my hand in vacuum, so what force will my hands apply?
If no force is applied then I must be able to move my hands continuously in vacuum without getting tired.

Comment: Your muscle does feel a stress when you stretched them?

Answer (score 2):

### Newton's second law

Whenever you apply a net force on a body, the body starts accelerating. This is basically the Newton's second law, $\mathbf F_{\text{net}}=m \mathbf a$, where m is the mass of the body.

### General case in vacuum

If I apply a force on something in vacuum, that body will accelerate as there is some net force on it. And thus due to its acceleration, its velocity will increase. Let's say that now you remove the force, then the body continues to move with the velocity which it had at the time you stopped applying the force. Essentially, its acceleration becomes zero and thus itd velocity stays constant. It will continue moving with this velocity until some other force acts on it and changes its velocity.

### Your specific case

In your case, first you would have to apply some force to accelerate your hands and give them some velocity. Once you have done that, you can stop applying the force and your hands will continue moving with a constant velocity, as long as they are not acted upon by another force. But since our hands and arms are of finite length, so soon enough our hands will reach their maximum distance, and thus get pulled back to you by your muscles.

If you would have thrown a ball in vacuum, then it would go indefinitely with the same velocity (with which it left your hand) untill some other force acts on it.

Answer (score 1):

**Force is fundamentally, the interaction between two bodies.**

The analogy of hand that you are providing can be explained like this:

Imagine holding a rubber-band and stretching that is zero gravity. You are doing work, right? *which is stored in the rubber band*. You moving your arms in space is the same thing, just that, the *rubber-band* is intrinsic to your body.